# Signing a letter to a company you're suing

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am replying a letter to a letter a company send me I am currently going though the courts with. I used to work for this company and the director is not on my Christmas card list.

What is a funny/blunt/sends a message/harsh way to sign the letter at the end?

Something a little better than "Yours sincerely".

Comment: If you're going through the courts, I'd recommend keeping all communications to involved parties as professional as possible.

Comment: One that keeps up with the above while not implying any positive tone is *Respectfully,* - not humorous as requested though.

Comment: If you are going through the courts, do not reply. Give the letter to your legal representative. I am not a solicitor.

Comment: Well thank you everyone, unfortunately I have been down-voted and closed (which I understand) I have taken your advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My co-worker once made a mistake while writing an email (luckily caught before sending), which I think would fit the bill here.

*Best regrets,*

*sign*